# How to return a pandas dataframe and write a csv file without the function returning a tuple?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So during my last line of function, I wrote something like:

`return pd.DataFrame(data), pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv(folder_path + '/' + csv_name)`

It creates a csv file in the directory I want correctly, but the object created out of the function is a tuple instead of a pd dataframe.

Is there a way I can make my function do both things at once?

Comment: Write the line `pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv(folder_path + '/' + csv_name)` before return function and return only pd.DataFrame(data). Multiple returns will give outputs in tuple format. More to it, to_csv is an action not a object to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning the dataframe and the output of `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv` (which is `None`) at the same time, that's why you're getting a tuple. To solve it, do it separately:

```
def myfunc():
    ...
    #whatever the function does
    ...
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.to_csv(folder_path + '/' + csv_name)
    return df
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do it this way.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv(folder_path + '/' + csv_name)
return df
```

or if you want to return as you have right now then.
while calling the function you can do below thing.

```
df,_=fun()
```

as your function returns two things (df and None).